A question about POSIX semaphores and compatibility between different Linux distros
If I create a POSIX semaphore at the system root as such :
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

std::string semName = "/MySemaphore" ;

int main(void)
{
    sem_t* MySemaphore = sem_open(semName.c_str(), O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IGRP | S_IWGRP, 0) ;
    // uses for synchronization with another process until its no longer needed
    sem_close(MySemaphore) ;
    sem_unlink(semName.c_str()) ;

    return 0 ;
}

Will this be compatible between different distros? will anything get upset about creating semaphores at the system root like this?

Well, there is POSIX.1-2008 and POSIX.1-2001, which are different. This is part of libpthread library implementation, it depends what you're up to.

@AlanBirtles not really, at work I deal with hardware running linux that doesn't even have libpthread support, It's likeasking if this particular pump can be used to  pressurize tires of every car in world (there are some that don't have pressurized tires). Distros not supporting 2008 spec may ignore last option. Or may not support some of mode flags,though afaik all these are standard https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html


"will anything get upset about creating semaphores at the system root
like this?"

The name given to the semaphore is not a real file system path, it's just a name that identifies the semaphore for IPC (inter-process communication).
The relavant information in the documentation is that:

creates a new POSIX semaphore or opens an existing semaphore. The
semaphore is identified by name.


A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form /somename; that
is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX-4 (i.e., 251)
characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more
characters, none of which are slashes. Two processes can operate on
the same named semaphore by passing the same name to sem_open(3).

Therefore your code (using the valid name "/MySemaphore") should perform as you expect on any Linux system.

Three semaphore name has to start with a single slash and contain no other slashes:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html

A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to
NAME_MAX-4 (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial
slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which
are slashes

Therefore your code should work on any Linux system.
This isn't creating a file in the root of your filesystem, it's creating a file somewhere else:

On Linux, named semaphores are created in a virtual filesystem,
normally mounted under /dev/shm, with names of the form
sem.somename.

